# caught segfault, memory not mapped error in Rcpp trying to implement a function

Tags: r, mergesort, rcpp

i'm new in Rcpp and i dont really know Rcpp. but as a personal project, i was trying to run some sort algorithms using some C code that i had, converting them to R with Rcpp.

But i'm getting the memory not mapped error, and i dont really understand what i'm doing wrong, so if someone could enlighten me :)

The problem happens when a try the following code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

void intercala(int p, int q, int r, NumericVector v)
{
  int i, j, k;
  NumericVector w = NumericVector::create();

   i = p;
   j = q;
   k = 0;


   while (i < q && j < r) {
      if (v[i] < v[j]) {
         w[k] = v[i];
         i++;
      }
      else {
         w[k] = v[j];
         j++;
      }
      k++;
   }
   while (i < q) {
      w[k] = v[i];
      i++;
      k++;
   }
   while (j < r) {
      w[k] = v[j];
      j++;
      k++;
   }
   for (i = p; i < r; i++)
      v[i] = w[i-p];
}

void mergesort(int p, int r, NumericVector v)
{
   int q;
   if (p < r - 1) {
      q = (p + r) / 2;
      mergesort(p, q, v);
      mergesort(q, r, v);
      intercala(p, q, r, v);
   }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector mergesortC(NumericVector vetor) {
  int n = vetor.size();
  mergesort(0,n,vetor);
  return vetor;
}
```

This code is in a file called merge.cpp

Them when i try to run on R

```
    > library(Rcpp)
    > sourceCpp("merge.cpp")
    > vetor<-sample(1:10)
    > vetor
     [1]  1  5  7  4  3  8  9  2 10  6
    > mergesortC(vetor)
     [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
    > vetor

     *** caught segfault ***
    address 0x8, cause 'memory not mapped'

    Possible actions:
    1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
    2: normal R exit
    3: exit R without saving workspace
    4: exit R saving workspace
    Selection:
```

It seems to me that i'm doing something that i shouldn't, but the code seem to work in the begin, then i somehow mess with the memory in the object vetor. I managed to work on other algorithms with Rcpp, but this one wont work, and i dont understand what i'm doing wrong, so if anyone could spare a moment.

Comment: `NumericVector w = NumericVector::create();` creates a numeric vector of length 0 -- which you then attempt to populate with values. You probably want to initialize a vector with some pre-allocated size (note that Rcpp vectors do not grow efficiently, as e.g. `std::vector` does -- but why not use `std::vector<double>` there anyhow? Also, you should be pre-allocating / using `push_back()` anyhow, I think)

Comment: Good comment, but let's stress that we do *not* recommend `push_back()` on Rcpp vectors as the underlying `SEXP` would need to get copied for each alteration -- very inefficient.

Comment: @Augusto: That is a fair start, but I recommend that you read at least a little bit about Rcpp, and/or study some examples.

Comment: Right, sorry -- I meant to imply that it seems using `std::vector<double>` for `w` here, alongside `vector::push_back`, would likely be preferable.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I guess i got overexcited when everything started working, i'm reading [link](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html) tutorial right now.